# Json Object Length is returning zero Javascript

Tags: angularjs, json

This is my json object adminDocs in angularJS.

```
[] 0: {rowno: 1,  docTypeDesc: "Passport photocopy", …} 1: {rowno: 2, docTypeDesc: "Birth Certificate", …} 2: {rowno: 3, docTypeDesc: "Admission Doc Literature", …} 3: {rowno: 4, docTypeDesc: "Transcript", …} length: 4 __proto__: Array(0)
```

Checking `$scope.adminDocs.length` is returning zero.

Comment: The problem must be somewhere else. Please post a complete reproducible example.

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.adminDocs))` and see what you get

Comment: You must be checking it when the object did not have the data assigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue is not with $scope.adminDocs.length returning zero. The object's value is not returned untill it is completely loaded. So, it is returning zero.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
var count = Object.keys(adminDocs).length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to parse the object and then use:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(*your JSON*);
var length = Object.keys(obj).length;
```

Comment: i got error SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)